# Ruby on Rails: Post.comments.last get id error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I can't seem to work this out. Please help me out. I have a post and comment model. My post model looks like this:

```
post.rb
has_many :comments
```

This is the comment model:

```
comment.rb
belongs_to :comment
```

In my Post index view, I wrote this code:

```
index.html.erb
<tbody>
        <% @Posts.each do |post| %>
          <tr>
            <td><%= post.comments.last %></td>
          </tr>
        <% end %>
      </tbody>
```

This seems to work and gives me this value:

```
#<Comment:0x007f6b34bfca88>
```

but when I change to code to this:

```
<tbody>
        <% @Posts.each do |post| %>
          <tr>
            <td><%= post.comments.last.id %></td>
          </tr>
        <% end %>
      </tbody>
```

It gives me this error

```
undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass
```

What I wanted to achieve was to get the id of the last comment in my view. If you have answer to this problem, let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like one of your posts doesn't have any comments. Change your code to `post.comments.last.try(:id)`.

Comment: @moveson hey it works!! Thank you sir! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like some posts do not have comments - and therefore `post.comments.last` returns `nil`. In your original code, that just resulted in an empty cell in your table.

Try this:

```
<tbody>
  <% @Posts.each do |post| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= post.comments.last.try(:id) %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</tbody>
```

That will return an `id` where there are comments, and an empty cell where there are no comments

Comment: If you're using Ruby 2.4 there's also the new syntax `post.comments.last&.id` which returns `nil` if `last` is `nil` and doesn't throw an error.

Comment: Thanks @ReggieB it works now. The problem was that I have empty comments in other posts, but in others there are comments. Didn't expect the problem would be from post that has no comments. Thanks!

Comment: @Lorelyn It's not a problem, **if** you use `try` or `&.`. You cannot access something that doesn't exist, so if some of your posts have comments and some don't, you need to handle that.